# custome user serializer giving error on is_valid() - django

Tags: python, django, validation, object, serialization

For some reason I am not using form model to create the user form and so on so I am not using the `form.is_valid()`

I went through online and was taught to create a serializer like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
```

I tried creating a new user object in python shell then use the serializers on the object then uses the `is_valid()` but it gives me false instead of true, also the password being created is not hashed too, it was just a string

I did something like this in python shell. (also tried one that has id too but the result is the same so I didn't bother pasting it again)

```
user1 = User.objects.create(username='username', email='email@email.com', password='password')

user1_s = UserModelSerializer(user1)
```

when I run `user1_s` this came up

```
UserModelSerializer(<User: username>):
id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
username = CharField(help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, validators=[<django.contrib.auth.validators.ASCIIUsernameValidator object>, <UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
password = CharField(max_length=128)
```

run `user1_s.data`

```
{'username': u'username', 'password': u'password', 'id': 4, 'email': u'email@email.com'}
```

run `user1_s = UserModelSerializer(data=user1)`

run `user1_s.is_valid()` and `False` is returned

run `user1_s.errors`

```
{u'non_field_errors': [u'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got User.']}
```

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
Can someone please let me know how I am doing this wrong and direct me to the right direction please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of misconceptions here.

Firstly, the password is not hashed because you are not calling any method that hashes it. When you create a user, you must always call `create_user`, not `create`; it is the former that hashes the password.

```
user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='username', email='email@email.com', password='password')
```

Secondly, the reason `user1_s` is invalid is clearly explained in the error message: when you want to pass data into a serializer and get a User object out, you need to actually pass a dictionary of data in and not a User object.

So, as a test, this would work:

```
user1_serialize = UserModelSerializer(user1)
data = user1_serialize.data
user1_deserialize = UserModelSerializer(data=data)
user1_deserialize.is_valid()
```